# Testing a node command line app with jasmine-node

Tags: javascript, tdd, jasmine, bdd

How exactly would I go about testing a node-based CLI with `Jasmine`/`jasmine-node`? I have tested node modules in the past with `Jasmine`, which was easy, as I would merely require in the module in the spec file, initialise it and test it, but obviously that's different with a CLI. Obviously one method would be to convert it into a class and test it on its own, then convert it into a CLI, but that's not the real deal. Has anyone successfully tested a node CLI with Jasmine?

Answer (score 1):

Like any good unix citizen, a node CLI app should support stdout redirection. If it does so, it then becomes pretty trivial to test it, by storing the buffer and running assertions on it when it ends. This testing strategy uses [tape](https://github.com/substack/tape), but the general concepts of spawning a process and running assertions on its stdout should be transferable to another test framework.

```
var test = require('tape');
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
var path = require('path');
var read = require('fs').readFileSync;

test('binary', function (t) {
    t.plan(3);

    process.chdir(__dirname);

    var ps = spawn(process.execPath, [
        path.resolve(__dirname, '../bin/cmd.js'),
        'fixture.txt'
    ]);

    var out = '';
    var err = '';
    ps.stdout.on('data', function (buffer) { out += buffer; });
    ps.stderr.on('data', function (buffer) { err += buffer; });

    ps.on('exit', function (code) {
        var expected = read('expected.txt', 'utf-8');
        t.notOk(err, 'should not error');
        t.equal(code, 0, 'should exit with code 0');
        t.equal(out, expected, 'should perform the transform');
    });
});
```

This CLI app takes a text file as its first parameter and runs it through a transform. All you have to do is provide a fixture and expected result and then run the test.

Comment: It's good that you provide code to test the actual CLI and not the usual "back-door" testing of the nodejs code. But unfortunately the code does not work with jasmine.

Answer (score 0):

To run all tests in certain folder from CLI

On windows, from command prompt:

```
"<PATH TO NODE IF NOT IN ENV>\node.exe" "<PATH TO JASMINE-NODE MODULE>\jasmine-node\lib\jasmine-node\cli.js --verbose --test-dir <PATH TO SPECS>
```

Example:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node.exe" "c:\MyProject\node_modules\jasmine-node\lib\jasmine-node\cli.js" --verbose --test-dir c:\MyProject\Specs
```

Check docs on git:

https://github.com/mhevery/jasmine-node

https://github.com/mhevery/jasmine-node/wiki/Command-Line-Usage